# Specific error message in php mailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, cpanel, host

i'm usig php mailer to send email via SMTP using HTML form, recently this error ocured when i'm trying to send that email: 
"SMTP server error: 5.7.1 Mail (id-40257-40235) appears to be unsolicited, please resend with the code sy2ururu appended to email subject and ask to have your sender email whitelisted (the code sy2ururu changes each 24 hours)."

What could it mean? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SMTP error 5.7.1 is Unable to Relay so the user who is sending the email does not have permissions to the mail server.

you can check PHP.ini for the key sendmail_from as the default is...

```
sendmail_from = you@yourdomain
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it was the password i've change it but not in the script :D